# Why functions are objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Please, explain to me why functions are objects in javascript?
An object is a structure with properties. Value of property may be a function and we call this property - method.
But we can NOT execute an object.
We can NOT do this:

```
var cat = {name: 'Murzik', age: 17};
cat();
```

But we can execute the function

```
var func = function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
};
func();
```

So, if functions are objects why we can do this?
Please, help me to understand!
Thank's!

Comment: The designers of Javascript simply decided that a function would be derived from an object and thus could have properties itself.  What other kind of answer are you looking for?  An array is also derived from an object.  A function is a derived object, thus is has all the capabilities of a regular object plus some additional ones that are added in the derived implementation.  This is how inheritance works.

Comment: If you really are serious about javascript and understanding its differences from other languages I would pick up a copy of JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford.  If you think functions have a funky taste in javascript, you'll love things like truthy/falsey, closures, and javascript math.  0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 is false.

Comment: functions are objects but objects are not functions. What does this mean? [`is a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) is not equivalence.

Comment: @Lawrence - float math equivalence quirks are not unique to JavaScript.

Comment: Not unique but among the land mines :)

Answer (score 3):

Because the ECMAScript spec says so:

> [**4.3.24 function**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.24)
>
> member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in
>   `Function` constructor and that may be invoked as a subroutine

Note that

- Some objects are not callable:

  ```
  var obj = {};
  typeof obj; // "object" --> It's not callable
  obj(); // TypeError: obj is not a function
  ```
- Some objects are callable but are not functions:

  ```
  var obj = document.createElement('object');
  typeof obj; // "function" --> It's callable
  obj instanceof Function; // false --> It's not a function
  ```
- Some objects are callable and are functions:

  ```
  function obj(){}
  typeof obj; // "function" --> It's callable
  obj instanceof Function; // true --> It's a Function instance
  ```
- Not all `Function` instances are callable:

  ```
  var obj = Object.create(Function.prototype);
  obj instanceof Function; // true --> It's a Function instance
  typeof obj; // "object" --> It's not callable
  obj(); // TypeError: obj is not a function
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way the language is designed. Functions are reference types (they are passed as pointers), and JavaScript reference types may have sub-references. I think you are struggling to reconcile a model of objects from C++ or Java (structs with privileged methods) with the type sugar another language provides.

I am not sure at what point Brendan Eich chose to implement functions as an instance of objects, but I suspect the reasoning was that it was consistent with making functions first-class variables. Objects already existed as a type of variable and it perhaps made sense to model functions using an existing variable type. You would have to ask him directly.

One handy side effect is that it allows us to store metadata on a function. This can be handy when performing caching or doing anything else that requires state to be held between function calls:

```
function myCachedFunction(argument) {
    myCachedFunction.cache = myCachedFunction.cache || {};
    myCachedFunction.cache[argument] = myCachedFunction.cache[argument] || operation();

    return myCachedFunction.cache[argument];

    function operation() {
        // performs action with argument
        // only gets called if no cache lookup for argument
    }
}
```

Some functions also need to know when they've been called. This can be achieved by closure variables, but function fields can sometimes be a more elegant solution:

```
function getUniqueID() {
    getUniqueID._calls = getUniqueID._calls || 0;
    return getUniqueID._calls++;
}
```

Comment: Having `apply` and `toString` would not even necessitate any special cases when functions were primitive values. Methods work for other primitive types just as well

Comment: @Bergi - yes, that's true. I guess that can't be the reasoning behind the design, then. Although I note that the way methods on primitives is pretty incoherent - you can assign fields on a string, but the assignments fall into a black hole. You might argue the inconsistency is with the primitives rather than with the functions; I wonder if Eich and co just felt that e.g. extending string was just 'too weird', and so broke their own model to keep things 'intuitive'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because they are... thats what the designers of the language decided to do.

Answer (score -1):

What would you expect to happen if an object were callable? You can think of an object as storage and a function as something you can execute. Also, functions are not objects but they are a superset of them. Due to this libraries like jquery are possible as is prototypical inheritance which is how you make a class in JavaScript.

```
function Car() {
    this.tires = 4;
}

Car.prototype.hi = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}

var myCar = new Car();

console.log(myCar.tires); // 4
myCar.hi(); // hi
```

And static methods

```
Car.bye = function() {
    console.log("bye");
}

Car.bye(); // bye
myCar.bye(); // this is an error
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain it in english... :(
I don't understand how functions are looks like? If we have a method in an object, we can call it, of course.

    `var obj = { method: function() { alert(1) } };
    obj.method();`

But how we can call the function? What method we are calling, when we call the function, if we think that an object is a storage with properties.

Comment: @Kotik - there is no method call. Functions are just a reference type that have the extra ability to dereference to a procedure.

Comment: @Kotik: We call an internal "call" method that you cannot see.