# Why a function is a subset of an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type ccc = (() => 22) extends Record<string|symbol,any> ? true : false // true
```

I don't understand why it was designed this way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why functions are objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528679/why-functions-are-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Because a function is an object in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are `Function` objects.